# UI uses values of old components

Tags: uwp, binding, uwp-xaml

[This](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oLSHzpJCs_mfwEhu7zGzFa8NzBnJBxXo?usp=sharing) is the demo code I created.

When I remove an element in the `ObservableCollection` and then insert a new element, it seems the UI of new element is somehow displaying the value of the removed element.

For example, when I clicked the remove button and then the add button, there should be a new `TestTemplate` object with a null `InnerTestTemplate` value. However, the new object will still have the old `InnerTestTemplate` value of the removed element.

Besides, I found the `InitializeComponent()` is not always called when a `TestTemplate` is newed. That is, when I check the top most checkbox, click the remove button and then click the add button, the checkbox of the uppermost checkbox remains checked, which is not supposed to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add constructors for `InnerTestTemplate` class and `TestTemplate` class, and then `TestTemplate` object will has a null `InnerTestTemplate` value.

```
public InnerTestTemplate()
{
    //......
}

public TestTemplate()
{
    _innerTestTemplate = new InnerTestTemplate();
}
```

About the re-usage of deleted `CheckBox`, you could cancel virtualization of `ListView` if the count of items in `ListView` is not large. Add the following code in your `ListView` which uses a `StackPanel` to replace the default one：

```
<ListView ……>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        ……
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization), the virtualization of  `ListView` is more like how and when to render the items in the `ListView`. Is this the reason why the new `CheckBox` is display the value of the old one?